# Bokeh how to add hover for multi bar graph

Tags: python, bokeh

I am new to `bokeh` and facing some problem with hover feature.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge

output_file("dodged_bars.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=fruits, y_range=(0, 10), plot_height=250, title="Fruit counts by year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits', -0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2015', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#c9d9d3", legend_label="2015")

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.0,  range=p.x_range), top='2016', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#718dbf", legend_label="2016")

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2017', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#e84d60", legend_label="2017")
hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips = """
<div>
    <div><strong>fruits:  </strong>@fruits</div>
    <div><strong>Count: </strong>@name</div>
</div>"""
p.add_tools(hover)
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

Please help me understand how to add hover feature for multigraph.i guess glyph or something else is missing
[image]

In this image ??? shows instead of value.

Comment: You need to describe what the current behavior is and how it differs from your expectations. Screenshots are also always helpful.

Comment: i have uploaded the image of current behavior.kindly check

Comment: Where the tooltip/hover show ??? You ask for @name but prefix with the label count. This looks unintended

Comment: PLease check the attached image . hover in front of count shows ??? . what value should i mentioned instead of "count" to it to work.I have tried it with "years" as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
p.vbar(... name='2015',legend_label="2015")
p.vbar(... name='2016',legend_label="2016")
p.vbar(... name='2017',legend_label="2017")
```

and

```
<div>
<div><strong>fruits:  </strong>@fruits</div>
<div><strong>Count: </strong> @$name</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: strange it works for me ...did you change  @name ->  @$name ?

Comment: @CheckTest This is definitely the correct approach (see the screenshot I added). Please check that you have applied it exactly, as suggested. You can see this same approach working in a live plot in the docs: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#tooltips